# Prove $s^k(n) \neq n$

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Basically the title. By $s$ I mean the function $s: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ defined by $s(n) = n + 1$. I only have induction, so I proved that $s(n) \neq n$, for the base of induction, and when I suppose $s^k(n) \neq n$, I can reach $s^{k+1}(n) \neq s(n)$, but in the left side I can't just put $n$.
I got that
$s^{k+1}(n) \neq s(n)$

$s(n) \neq n$

How can I conclude that $s^{k+1}(n) \neq n?$, since $\neq$ is not transitive? I guess I'm missing something really simple but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Since modulo $k$, $s^k(n) = n$, you'll have to take advantage of a property of natural numbers that isn't true of the integers mod $k$. Perhaps ordering?

Comment: Isn't it immediate that $s^k(n)=n+k$ even without induction [though induction would be a way to prove this formally]?  Then it's clear.

Comment: Maybe try induction with respect to $n$, as opposed to induction with respect to $k$.  (Though as a subproof, you might end up wanting to prove $s(s^k(n)) = s^k(s(n))$, and for that, induction with respect to $k$ would be useful.)

Comment: @Randall you're right. Knowing that $s^k(n) = n + k$ I can conclude that $s(k) = 1$ if $n + k = n$, which is a contradiction since $1 \notin s(\mathbb{N})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We claim that $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}^+, s^k(n)=n+k$. The proof is as follows:

Base case: $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, s^1(n)=s(n)=n+1$

Induction hypothesis: $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, s^k(n)=n+k$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Inductive step: We claim that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, s^{k+1}(n)=n+k+1$.

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, s^{k+1}(n)=s^k(s(n))=s^k(n+1)=n+1+k$ by our induction hypothesis.

$\therefore\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, s^{k+1}(n)=n+k+1$. This completes the induction.

Now from our claim, we have that $\forall k, n\in\mathbb{N}, s^k(n)=n+k\neq n$.